# Android (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzx;

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling

I am trying to find where the error is.
I would be delighted if you help me for this, at least to know where to start from debugging.

*FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
Process: es.mrjeff.app.android.jeff, PID: 1943
                                                                      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzx;
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzaU(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1686)
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1655)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4964)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4559)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4499)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/es.mrjeff.app.android.jeff/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-22.2.1_c88a2eaa5245cd30e618969f1b8d0f07b45957fc-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.mrjeff.app.android.jeff/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.mrjeff.app.android.jeff/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.mrjeff.app.android.jeff/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.mrjeff.app.android.jeff/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-measurement-8.3.0_ef550eb40b5fb4f7a179f5cad46917a075c16186-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/es.mrjeff.app.android.jeff/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.facebook.android-facebook-android-sdk-4.6.0_4be70ad9b89901240fcc3a8cfa19306d134fc2e0-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/es.mrjeff.app.android.jeff-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                          at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzaU(Unknown Source) 
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1686) 
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1655) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4964) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4559) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4499) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
                                                                        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/es.mrjeff.app.android.jeff-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/es.mrjeff.app.android.jeff-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                ... 17 more*
```

Comment: which version of play services are you using?

Comment: @SripadRaj I am using 8.3.0

Comment: can you try with 8.4.0?

Comment: @SripadRaj it didnt work... it says: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

Comment: @SripadRaj this is the error that popped up after updating play services as you said..

Comment: are you using this for your notifications??